# delete triggers exception in "_CRTDECL operator delete" in delete_scalar.cpp

Tags: c++, winapi, delete-operator

I am writing a WinAPI application in C++.

**Situation**

I initialize `Interface` class in `wWinMain` and store the pointer to it into `GWLP_USERDATA` like so:

```
WinMain(...)
{
    ...

    //  INITIALIZE CUSTOM INTERFACE
    Interface* p_inface{new Interface(hWnd)}; // Create class object
    SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(p_inface)); // to retrieve it in callback

    ...
}
```

I initialize it like this because the `Interface` class initializes subclassed controls which require `HWND` to already exist, and I prefer my classes to fully initialize automatically in constructor.

In my `WndProc` callback I want to delete it like so:

```
WndProc(...)
{
    ...

    case WM_NCDESTROY:
    {
        Interface* p_inface{reinterpret_cast<Interface*>(GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA))};
        delete p_inface;
    }
    break;

    ...
}
```

`Interface` class header:

```
class Interface
{
    public:

    Interface(HWND const hWndParam);
    ~Interface();

    private:

    std::shared_ptr<Time> const p_time; // object holding timeframe information
    std::unique_ptr<Calendar> const p_calendar; // object handling calendar interface
    std::unique_ptr<MainMinimize> const p_minimize; // minimize button
    std::unique_ptr<MainClose> const p_close; // close button

    Interface(const Interface&) = delete;
    Interface& operator=(const Interface&) = delete;
};
```

And class project file:

```
Interface::Interface
(
    HWND const hWndParam // handle to main window
)
    : p_time(std::make_shared<Time>())
    , p_calendar{std::make_unique<Calendar>(p_time, hWndParam)}
    , p_minimize{std::make_unique<MainMinimize>(hWndParam)}
    , p_close{std::make_unique<MainClose>(hWndParam)}
{
}

Interface::~Interface()
{
}
```

**Problem**

I am getting exception pointing here (in delete_scalar.cpp) when the application tries to `delete` the `p_inface` pointer in `WM_NCDESTROY` of `WndProc`:

```
_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK); // << EXCEPTION: APPLICATION TRIGGERED BREAKPOINT
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

I can't figure out why. I tried removing `const` from internal objects (didn't do the trick) and also reseting internal `Interface` class objects in destructor (this too didn't solve the issue).

When debugging I found that the pointer in WndProc is correct, and all objects within it except for `Time` `shared_ptr` are already wiped. They are intact in WM_DESTROY message though.

When looking for solutions I mostly found it triggering for people deleting objects on stack or mixing `new` with `delete[]`. [One person](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24578711/delete-operator-triggering-user-breakpoint.html) mentioned *"Most likely, either the point is not pointing to a valid heap allocated object, the heap has already been deleted or some other code has corrupted the heap."*

**Question**

Can you please help me understand what mistake am I making and how to fix it so that the exception no longer triggers?

Comment: You can't determine that a pointer is valid by inspection, and all you can say about memory corruption problems is that someting has gone wrong somewhere at some point before you observe any symptoms.

Comment: @molbdnilo well it has the same addess, I was hoping that means it is still the same pointer. About memory corruption, this is the only pointer anywhere that is not unique_ptr or shared_ptr so it didn't occur to me it could actually be memory corruption. But you are right, I will look into that.

Comment: @molbdnilo internal objects are fine at WM_DESTROY and wiped at WM_NCDESTROY. Please do you have any idea what it could be hinting at?

Comment: You can't determine that an object is valid by inspection. Destroying an object does not magically change the value of all pointers to it, or change its values to something obviously invalid. Unfortunately, it's not even certain that your problems are related to that object at all.

Comment: @molbdnilo debuging takes me into Interface class destructor and goes through it without error (I put some random assignments there), so I was assuming that makes the object valid. Am I wrong?

Comment: in what problem set breakpoint inside `Interface::~Interface()` (add here some line like `DbgPrint` or `__nop()`) and look when and from where this called first time and next time. if crash is constant (but not random) - this is very good and easy can be found reason

Comment: Have a look at the call stack at the point the exception is raised. That'll help you understand, which deallocation is ultimately responsible. From there, work your way back.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Solving this problem requires careful reading and a lot of thinking. The debugger is of limited use.

Comment: And again: this particular object could be a red herring. Don't assume that the ultimate problem has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the actual `Interface` object (thanks molbdnilo!), but the order of processed information within one of the base classes.

All my control classes which subclass WinAPI controls are stored in `unique_ptr`s in objects deeper within the `Interface` object, so on `Interface` delete statement the cascading destructors cause all `unique_ptr`s down the road to automatically destruct their objects.

The problem was that when I was sneaking pointer of the class (subclassing the control) into it's callback function through dwRefData, I was also `deleting` it in WM_DESTROY message - but the object was long gone due to `unique_ptr` clean up which happened sooner than the `DESTROY` message could have reached the queue.

So the solution: don't try deleting objects which are already handled by smart pointers!

Comment: Hi Irma, feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).